# setting bias for multiclass classification python tensorflow keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

Attached [model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data) shows how to add bias in case of the unbalanced classification problem `initial_bias = np.log([pos/neg])`. Is there a way to add bias if you have multi-class classification with unbalanced data, Say 5 classes where classes are have distribution `(0.4,0.3,0.2.0.08 and 0.02)`

2) also how to calculate and use class weights in such case?

#### update 1

```
I found a way to apply weights, still not sure how to use bias

#####adding weights 20 Feb
weight_for_0 = ( 1/ 370)*(370+ 977+ 795)/3
weight_for_1 = ( 1/ 977)*(370+ 977+ 795)/3
weight_for_2 = (1 / 795)*(370+ 977+ 795)/3

#array([0, 1, 2]), array([370, 977, 795])

class_weights_dict = {0: weight_for_0, 1: weight_for_1, 2:weight_for_2}
class_weights_dict
Dcnn.fit(train_dataset,
         epochs=NB_EPOCHS,
         callbacks=[MyCustomCallback()],verbose=2,validation_data=test_dataset, class_weight=class_weights_dict)
```

Comment: Is this `'softmax'` + `'categorical_crossentropy'` (only one class is correct), or is this `"sigmoid"` + `"binary_crossentropy"` (many classes can be correct)?

Comment: only one class can be correct. i am using `sparse_categorical_accuracy` and `softmax`

Comment: That will be a very complex equation to solve... I wonder if there is something online....

Comment: when you mentioned `"sigmoid" + "binary_crossentropy" (many classes can be correct)` earlier, it was a binary classification right? How could you use `sigmoid` if there is more than 2 classes?

Comment: It's applied elementwise. Each element is a binary class. That's why many classes can be correct.

Comment: in such case do you build N models if there are N possible outputs? do you have example of such problem?

Comment: One model, output shape = `(None, classes)`. Exactly the same as a categorical model. But you use different activation and different loss.

Comment: Using the answer, below, for the case where the counts are `[370, 977, 795]`, the biases are `[-0.45752,  0.51344, 0.30730]`

Comment: in my original questions, i calculated weights for counts `[370, 977, 795]` . Based upon your answer I am not planning to use bias at all. My original problem has 7 classes. Calculating biases would be difficult. Let me know if you have any thoughts about using class weights only

Comment: I takes a little longer to converge, but I don't think it will be a problem not to use biases. But if you give me the frequencies or counts I can give you the biases.

Comment: appreciate that. Once you provide me an array of biases, how do i apply it?  `self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units=3,
                                           activation="softmax", bias_initializer=[-0.45752, 0.51344, 0.30730])`. That's all right? This is my last layer. Would my `fit` statement remain unchanged? `Dcnn.fit(train_dataset,
         epochs=NB_EPOCHS,
         callbacks=[MyCustomCallback()],verbose=2,validation_data=test_dataset, class_weight=class_weights_dict)`

Comment: It's in the answer below. Fit doesn't change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that you're using [`'softmax'`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function):

```
softmax = exp(neurons) / sum(exp(neurons))
```

And that you want the results of the classes to be:

```
frequency = [0.4 , 0.3 , 0.2 , 0.08 , 0.02]
```

Biases should be given by the equation (elementwise):

```
frequency = exp(biases) / sum(exp(biases))
```

This forms a system of equations:

- `f1 = e^b1 / (e^b1 + e^b2 + ... + e^b5)`
- `f2 = e^b2 / (e^b1 + e^b2 + ... + e^b5)`
- ...
- `f5 = e^b5 / (e^b1 + e^b2 + ... + e^b5)`

If you can solve this system of equations, you get the biases you want.

I used excel and test-error method to determine that for the frequencies you wanted, your biases should be respectively:

```
[1.1 , 0.81 , 0.4 , -0.51 , -1.9]
```

I don't really know how to solve that system easily, but you can keep experimenting with excel or another thing until you reach the solution.

---

Adding the biases to the layer - method 1.

Use a name when defining the layer, like:

```
self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units=3, activation="softmax", name='last_layer')
```

You may need to build the model first, so:

```
dummy_predictions = model.predict(np.zeros((1,) + input_shape))
```

Then you get the weights:

```
weights_and_biases = model.get_layer('last_layer').get_weights()
w, b = weights_and_biases
new_biases = np.array([-0.45752, 0.51344, 0.30730])
model.get_layer('last_layer').set_weights([w, new_biases])
```

**Method 2**

```
def bias_init(bias_shape):
    return K.variable([-0.45752, 0.51344, 0.30730])

self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units=3, activation="softmax", bias_initializer=bias_init)
```

Comment: I am not clear. If we know b1, b2,...b5 then why cannot we find f1,f2,...f5 by direct formula that you have mentioned above?  Why do we have to experiment in excel?

Comment: @user2543622, You don't know `b1` and others, they are the biases. You know `f1` and others, they are the frequencies, in your example `[0.4 , 0.3 , 0.2 , 0.08 , 0.02]`.

Comment: what is K in `K.variable([-0.45752, 0.51344, 0.30730])`? is it `import keras as K` or is it `import tensorflow.keras.backend as K?` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/variable)

Comment: @user2543622, it's `keras.backend` or `tensorflow.keras.backend`. (The one you're using)

Comment: also if i understand correctly, if you take a random sample then go for bias+weights. If you go for up sampling or down sampling so that your training data is equally distributed then go for bias only. is that correct?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You change only biases if your data is unbalanced. That's all.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data, they have unbalanced data. They start with random sample and add bias and add class weights. Then in a new approach they sample again such that there is even distribution of both Ys and they still go for bias.

Comment: Ahh, "sample weights", yes. They are more important than the biases. (I thought you were talking about model weights). If you have a model that is already trained, you definitely don't want to change it. The only moment when you'd want to change the biases is when you create the model for the first time. ---- If they resample and use the same model, they don't touch the biases (but should change class weights). If they resample and create a new model, then they should calculate new biases.

Comment: let me rephrase. I have unbalanced multiclass classification problem. I havent built any model as of now. My approaches going to be below. do they make sense?
model1) take random sample of the data and build model using class weights provide all classes are equally important. Avoid bias as it is difficult to calculate  
model2) take random sample and build model using class weights, adjust class weights if a class is more imp than others 
model3) take upsample or downsample so that all classes have equal presentation and build model without class weights. this option is comparable to model1

Comment: You need to test. Every data is different, every model is different.

Answer (score 3):

Just in addition to @Daniel Möller's answer, to solve the system of equations

- `f1 = e^b1 / (e^b1 + e^b2 + ... + e^b5)`

  ...
- `f5 = e^b5 / (e^b1 + e^b2 + ... + e^b5)`

You don't need excel or anything. Just compute `bi = ln(fi)`.

Comment: Yeah, the answer is a bit misleading. I did the calculations and it was this simple. Also, the biases are invariant to addition by a constant number. So, `b_i = ln(f_i) + c` are the right set biases.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate `fi = e^bi / (sum of e^bj)`, note that `fi/fj = e^(bi-bj)`. Suppose the lowest frequency is fk. You can set `bk= 0` and then compute every other class bias with `bi = bj + ln(fi/fj)`.

Answer (score 1):

A complete answer is here:

```py
### To solve that set of nonlinear equations, use scipy fsolve
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from math import exp

# define the frequency of different classes
f=(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.08, 0.02)

# define the equation 
def eqn(x, frequency):
  sum_exp = sum([exp(x_i) for x_i in x])
  return [exp(x[i])/sum_exp - frequency[i] for i in range(len(frequency))]

# calculate bias init
bias_init = fsolve(func=eqn,
                  x0=[0]*len(f),
                  ).tolist()

bias_init
```

#### To put all things together

```py
def init_imbalanced_class_weight_bias(df:pd.DataFrame, lable:str):
  """To handle imbalanced classification, provide initial bias list and class weight dictionary to 2 places in a tf classifier
  
  1) In the last layer of classifier: tf.keras.layers.Dense(..., bias_initializer = bias_init)
  2) model.fit(train_ds, #x=dict(X_train), y=y_train, 
                batch_size=batch_size, 
                validation_data= valid_ds, #(dict(X_test), y_test), 
                epochs=epochs, 
                callbacks=callbacks,
                class_weight=class_weight,
                )
  Args:
    df:pd.DataFrame=train_df
    label:str
  Returns:
    class_weight:dict, e.g. {0: 1.6282051282051282, 1: 0.7604790419161677, 2: 0.9338235294117647}
    bias_init:list e.g. [0.3222079660508266, 0.1168690393701237, -0.43907701967633633]
  Examples:
    class_weight, bias_init = init_imbalanced_class_weight_bias(df=train_df, lable=label)
  References: 
  1. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data
  2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307239/setting-bias-for-multiclass-classification-python-tensorflow-keras#new-answer
  
  """
  from scipy.optimize import fsolve
  from math import exp

  # to deal with imbalance classification, calculate class_weight 
  d = dict(df[label].value_counts())
  m = np.mean(list(d.values()))
  class_weight = {k:m/v for (k,v) in d.items()} #e.g. {0: 1.6282051282051282, 1: 0.7604790419161677, 2: 0.9338235294117647}
  
  # define classes frequency list
  frequency = list(list(d.values())/sum(d.values()))

  # define equations to solve initial bias
  def eqn(x, frequency=frequency):
      sum_exp = sum([exp(x_i) for x_i in x])
      return [exp(x[i])/sum_exp - frequency[i] for i in range(len(frequency))]

  # calculate init bias
  bias_init = fsolve(func=eqn,
                    x0=[0]*len(frequency),
                    ).tolist()

  return class_weight, bias_init 

class_weight, bias_init = init_imbalanced_class_weight_bias(df=train_df, lable=label)
```

I will post a colab notebook if anyone interested.

In case your tf classifier complains about `ValueError: ('Could not interpret initializer identifier:'`, then add the `tf.keras.initializers.Constant()` around `bias_init`:

```py
def init_imbalanced_class_weight_bias(...)
   ...
   return class_weight, tf.keras.initializers.Constant(bias_init)
```

Comment: Can u post the notebook?